# Make Textfield overlap text when input in entered and expanded

Tags: swift, swiftui, overlap

I'm trying to make so when my "Search Field" (Textfield with a frame) expands I would like it to overlap the text/button. But instead it pushes the text/button down.
[image]

How can I changes this?
I've looking in to som GeometryReader but my expertise dosen't reach that far.

---

Class

```
struct SearchView: View {

@ObservedObject var allGames = SearchController()

var body: some View {
    
    NavigationView{
        ZStack(alignment: .top) {
            Color("Color").edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            
            VStack{
                
                SearchBar(data: self.allGames.allGames)
                    .padding(.top) <--- This needs to overlap RandomGameView when expanded
                
                RandomGameView()
                    .padding(.top)

            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Search")
        .padding(.top, -20)
    }
    .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
  }
}
```

Comment: For overlapping you need to play with ZStack instead of VStack, in latter below view will always be shifted down when upper view is expanded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are in the same V or HStack, when a view grows, it will push on all other views in that stack, so put it in a ZStack if you want it to go over top.

```
NavigationView{
    ZStack(alignment: .top) {
        Color("Color").edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        
        ZStack(alignment: .top) { // Make this a top aligned ZStack.
            
            SearchBar(data: self.allGames.allGames)
                .padding(.top)
            
            RandomGameView()
                .padding(.top)

        }
    }
    .navigationBarTitle("Search")
    .padding(.top, -20)
}
.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
.listStyle(PlainListStyle())
```